# Logging in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to figure out logging in Django (checking out Python logging itself for the first time too for that matter).

I have the following in my settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/afzalsh/logs/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

This is the exact code as what Django documentation has as the first example.

Then I have a log message in a class based view.

```
import logging
.
.
.
class StationHome(View):
    .
    .
    .
    def post(self,request, pk):
        station = Station.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form = StationForm(request.POST, instance=station)
        if form.is_valid():
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            logger.error("Yep!")
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home_station",
                                                kwargs={'pk':pk},
                                            )
                                    )
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Form Invalid")
.
.
.
```

The debug.log file has got created but it doesn't get populated with any message on going through the particular code. The expected process do happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've requested the logger associated with `__name__`, so you get one named the same as the current Python module. However, the only one you've actually configured is "django.request". You should use that in your call to `getLogger` instead.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. Could you tell me this; Initially I had passed `django.request` instead of `'django.request'` so my log file ended up getting populated with the corresponding error messages. I simply selected and deleted out the whole text. Then the "Yep" log message wasn't coming in thereafter. Only after I restarted the server it did. Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

In your settings your handler dict contains level 'debug' for file where as in your code you are using 'error' level to log.

```
logger.error("Yep!")
```

Try using 'debug' level in your code. Something like this:

```
logger.debug("Yep!")
```

also posting my settings here so that you can use that as a reference.

```
{
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'standard' : {
        'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
        'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
'handlers': {

    'console':{
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
    },
    'null' : {
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
    'file' : {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': 'debug.log',
        },
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'propogate': True,
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    'matchroom_app':{
        'handlers' : ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    'matchroom_post':{
        'handlers' : ['file'],
        'level' : 'DEBUG',
        },
    'matchroom_social':{
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level' : 'DEBUG',
        },
}
```

}

Comment: That's not it: DEBUG is the lowest level, so everything would be logged.

Comment: Oh. yes. Since DEBUG is the lowest level everything should be logged.
I think you got the correct answer. Anyways I hope my settings will help.